# How to map through and store an API response as an array of objects in state React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks, map-function

I am trying to map through a server side API response to store first three items in state as an array of objects with title and url key/value pairs. I am getting an "objects are not valid as React children" error when I run this code. How do I properly push objects to my articles useState array so that I can then map over the array to render them as links on my page? Thanks...

```js
const CodeNews = () => {

    const [articles, setArticles] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8000/apiKey')
        .then((res)=>{
            console.log(res)
            let tempArr = [];
            for(let i=0;i < 3; i++){
                tempArr.push({
                    title: res.data.articles[i].title,
                    url: res.data.articles[i].url
                })
            }
            setArticles(tempArr);
        })
        .catch((err)=>console.log(err))
    },[])
```

Comment: How do you render it?

Comment: That error is a rendering error. Show how you render `articles`

Comment: return(
        <div style={{display:"inline-block", color:"green"}}>
                    <h3> Recent News</h3>
                    {articles.map((article, idx)=>(
                    <p key={idx}>{article}</p>
                ))}
        </div>
    )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the solution will be to change the rendering method to something like this:

```
articles.map((el) => (
  <a href={el.url}>{el.title}</a>
))
```

This is because you can't render a whole object in JSX.

Comment: my rendering is set up like that already: {articles.map((article, idx)=>( <p key={idx}>{article}</p> but I think there is a problem with how I create and push article objects to the state array

Comment: Yes, but still: you are trying to render object in here:
<p key={idx}>{article}</p>
So let's replace it with:
<p key={idx}>{article.title}</p>

Comment: ah yes you are right! Thanks for sticking with me it's all working now, thanks Bart!